# how to use object entries when there is an object in an object

Tags: javascript, object

Currently I was wondering if it was possible and how to use object entries and map to get my desired result.

Currently, my data is:

```
let data = { 
  moreData: {one: 'one', two: '2', three: 'three'},
  city: 'New York',
  favFood: 'Steak',
  favSite: 'StackOverflow',
};
```

And my code is:

```
Object.entries(data).map(([key,value]) => value 
  ? console.log(`this is the ${key} and the value is: ${value}`)
  : ''
)
```

This will output:

```
"this is the moreData and the value is: [object Object]"
"this is the city and the value is: New York"
"this is the favFood and the value is: Steak"
"this is the favSite and the value is: StackOverflow"
```

However for the moreData object, I would like it to only pick the two: 'two', but I have no clue how to do this...

Is there anyone who could help me with this?

My desired result would be:

```
"this is the moreData and the value is: 2"
"this is the city and the value is: New York"
"this is the favFood and the value is: Steak"
"this is the favSite and the value is: StackOverflow"
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: A bit unclear on what you are trying. Are you looking to iterate the value object as well or just the `${value.two}` to be printed?

Comment: @nitishagar, my bad, I am trying to looking to iterate the value object as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do that would be setting a fallback when `value.two` does not exist (equals `null | undefined`).

```js
let data = { 
  moreData: {one: 'one', two: '2', three: 'three'},
  city: 'New York',
  favFood: 'Steak',
  favSite: 'StackOverflow',
};

Object.entries(data).map(([key,value]) => value 
  ? console.log(`this is the ${key} and the value is: ${value.two ?? value}`)
  : ''
)
```